# Event handlers for Underscore.js generated templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have my template in a separate file from the rest of the js code. I'm trying to do eventhandlers for my template (for example my onclick event below), but it doesn't work. Can anybody tell me how I can solve this?

```
var output = _.template($('#myTemplate').html(), {myData});
$('#content').html(output);

//This doesn't work
$('#myButton').click(function(){
      //Do something
});


//My template
<script type="text/template" id="myTemplate">
     <h2><%= myTitle %></h2>
     <button id="myButton">Button</button>
</script>
```

Comment: Is the template correctly inserted in the DOM? Is there only one element with ID `myButton`? Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: It seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/BzvmW/1/ That means the error is probably not in the code you posted and we cannot help you until you provide more information.

Comment: You have right. The code is working. There were other issues in the application. I'm sorry I wasted your time. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user1149117 I have similar issue, can you tell me what are the issues  on your site?

Comment: @user1149117 and how you fixed them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#myButton').live('click', function(){
      //Do something
});
```

Comment: That's the same as `$('#myButton').click(...)`. If one does not work, the other won't either.